# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when Moving Spring libraries from WEB-INF/lib to server/default/lib on JBoss AS 6

Tags: classloader, jboss6.x, spring-webflow-2

I'm trying to speedup my build process by moving Spring libraries from WEB-INF/lib to server/default/lib, but *unfortunately* i get this exception:

> Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossMojarra20
>   ConfigureListener: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationFactory

Answer (score 1):

JBoss contains its own JSF libraries and implementations. If you move the WebFlow libraries into JBoss's own library directories, you run the risk of these clashing with what's already present.

You need to be very careful adding stuff to JBoss's own classpath, it often gives weird side-effects and errors, like this one.

You need to either remove the JSF stuff from JBoss's internals (not easy), or keep the WebFlow libs where they belong - under `WEB-INF/lib`.